# Finding Fixed Points $x_{n+1}=x_n(r-x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-points

> Let $$x_{n+1}=x_n(r-x_n)$$ where $r$ is a parameter.
>
> a. Find the fixed points
>
> b. For which values of $r$ the iteration has a converge fixed points? For which fixed points converge in an area of a specific point? If there is a converge what is the order? If not Prove that it does not converge

a. we need to solve $$x=x(r-x)\Rightarrow x-x(r-x)=0\Rightarrow x(1-r+x)=0$$

So the fixed points are: $x=0$ and $x=r-1$

b. I know that there is something which $|g'(x)|<1$ and $|g'(x)|>1$ where $g(x)=x(r-x)$, but there is no interval to check it

Comment: I think you are looking for [attracting fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)#Attractive_fixed_points), aren't you?

Comment: @rtybase Yes, thanks, so I solved $|r-2x|<1$ and got $|r|<1+2x$

Comment: In fact $|r - 2x| < 1 \iff -1 < r - 2x < 1$. But, so far so good.

Comment: To summarise, you obtained $x_0=0$ and $x_1=r-1$. Now you need to find $r$'s for which $|g'(x_0)|<1$ and $|g'(x_1)|<1$ (not just any arbitrary $x$, only these $2$ fixed points!).